# Jenkins start-up fails after pointing to ssl cert and key

Tags: jenkins

- Jenkins 2.73.3
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)

The SSL cert and keys:

```
[root@l5109p ssl]# ls -lrt /etc/security/ssl/
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins  2894 Nov 27 09:17 jenkins_wildcard.sss.se.com.cert.pem
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins  1766 Nov 27 09:18 jenkins_wildcard.sss.se.com.key.pem
```

In the /etc/sysconfig/jenkins, I have added the following entry:

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--httpsPort=8443 --httpsCertificate=/etc/security/ssl/jenkins_wildcard.sss.se.com.cert.pem --httpsPrivateKey=/etc/security/ssl/jenkins_wildcard.sss.se.com.key.pem"
```

On starting the jenkins service, it fails with the following error:

```
Running from: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
Nov 27, 2017 9:42:17 AM Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /tmp/winstone/jenkins.war
Nov 27, 2017 9:42:17 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
INFO: Logging initialized @393ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
Nov 27, 2017 9:42:17 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Nov 27, 2017 9:42:17 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler setContextPath
WARNING: Empty contextPath
Nov 27, 2017 9:42:17 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory
        at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:209)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:150)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at Main._main(Main.java:294)
        at Main.main(Main.java:132)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not B64 encoded
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.B64Code.decode(B64Code.java:428)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.B64Code.decode(B64Code.java:391)
        at winstone.AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.readPEMRSAPrivateKey(AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.java:131)
        at winstone.AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.configureSsl(AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.java:75)
        at winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory.start(HttpsConnectorFactory.java:41)
        at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:207)
        ... 8 more
Nov 27, 2017 9:42:17 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory
        at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:209)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:150)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at Main._main(Main.java:294)
        at Main.main(Main.java:132)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not B64 encoded
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.B64Code.decode(B64Code.java:428)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.B64Code.decode(B64Code.java:391)
        at winstone.AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.readPEMRSAPrivateKey(AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.java:131)
        at winstone.AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.configureSsl(AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.java:75)
        at winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory.start(HttpsConnectorFactory.java:41)
        at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:207)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The log says the files are not in Base64.
Check these files, they should begin by one them :
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

And their content after the --- should be in Base64

Comment: Certificate has -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- -----END CERTIFICATE----- but the key has -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,2A44DDF99E96A424CF808B1A292441F7
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I thought those are already in encoded in Base64, am I missing something?

Comment: remove the line containing Proc-Type. You can send us the first line of your private key and we'll see if it looks like Base64 or not.

Comment: TFPvNTQnlsB/Kc4x0Ywj57fxAihtYo1BZnZJThBIok4KzAEzHmMaeRQRRIBC5E9s

Comment: it looks good, are you sure the first line contains the ---BEGIN, and that second starts with this line that you're giving here ? does this command return RSA key ok : `openssl rsa -in jenkins_wildcard.sss.se.com.key.pem -check` ?

Comment: [root@l5109p jenkins]# openssl rsa -in /etc/security/ssl/jenkins_wildcard.sss.se.scania.com.key.pem -check
unable to load Private Key
140234003765152:error:0906B06B:PEM routines:PEM_get_EVP_CIPHER_INFO:not proc type:pem_lib.c:505:

BTW, I have proceeded creating keystore approach and it works fine :)

Comment: OK, we can conclude that the private key was wrong, as the command didn't return the expected RSA key ok. Remember to mark posts as usefull when they are.